# Python. Регулярные выражения. Открыть файл и убрать все предложения по маске

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть файл с название "text.html"

нужно удалить все что начинаться от `</a><br><p>` и до `/enddd <br>`. 
Повторять удаление, пока элементы есть. Текст между этими флагами может быть разный. И перезаписать исправленный текст обратно в файл.

Примеры:

```
...</a><br><p>//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8 4/Michael Jordan Dep Of Defense/enddd <br>...
```

```
....jpg</a><br><p>//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/MJ golf course/enddd <br>MJ golf ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Регулярное выражение: `</a><br><p>.+/enddd <br>`.

***Пример:***

```py
import re


with open('text.html', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        lines[i] = re.sub(r'</a><br><p>.+/enddd <br>', '', lines[i])

    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(''.join(lines))
```

***UPD:***
Для нежадного поиска замените регулярное выражение на `</a><br><p>.+?/enddd <br>`.

Answer (score -3):

Ну например так:

```
a = #Сюда перенаправить элементы
a1 = a.replace("</a><br><p>","")
a2 = a1.replace("/enddd <br>","")
print (a2)
```

Думаю можно и проще, но додумался только до этого.

Comment: это замены что-то на что-то (на пустоту), но не от и до

Comment: @Юленька Только прочитав ваш комментарий понял что не понял задание) извиняюсь.